# Video processing on OpenCL kernel

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia

Is there a way to send a video as an argument to an OpenCL kernel, or can it only be sent frame by frame?
What is the correct approach for video processing over OpenCL kernel?

PS- I'm using NVidia GTX 1050Ti on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: If you want to access the frames as images then yes, pass them in as image objects. If you have a (compressed) video bitstream you want to process, pass it to the kernel as a memory buffer. In principle you can also pass image data (of any number of frames) as a memory object if you want to do the indexing yourself. I'm not really sure what else you're expecting?

Comment: I wanted to know if I could send the video bitstream as an argument. Thank you for clarifying that I can. :)

Comment: @pmdj Can you please tell me if something like Object Recognition/ Lane Detection is possible if we pass the video bitsteam as an argument to the kernel?

Comment: I'm not an expert on image recognition, but I suspect you'll want to decode frames first. Many GPUs have video decoding hardware, although the APIs to use for this are usually platform-specific. In many cases though you should be able to directly use decoded frame images still in GPU memory and pass them to an OpenCL kernel. Look at OpenCL extensions offered by your platform for this. Often you can "wrap" some other type of image object with a CL image object.

Comment: You can't send a continuous bitstream. You'd have to send it in chunks, such as frames or GOPs. It's not like you can hook up a bitstream to a kernel and have it continuously decode. That's not how it works. As others have said, probably better to decode on hardware or CPU and send frames to OpenCL kernels, one at a time. That's how it's done.

Comment: @Dithermaster I tried your approach and decoded the video on the CPU and sent the frames to OpenCL kernel one by one. The GPU load remained (2-5 %); checked it through _nvidia-smi_ . I am simply inverting the image for now i.e. subtracting 255 by the RGB values. Is this because the size of the frame (global work size) becomes very small? If so, what can I do to improve the performance ?

Comment: It is memory-bound. It's certainly not compute bound if it is one math operation per pixel.